# Script dies when parent process is terminated

Tags: linux, bash, shell, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a **.NET Core** service running on a **Debian 9**, let's call it *MyService*. At some point, this service is running a bash script `update.sh` using `Process.Start()` with `ShellExecute=true`.

As @omajid pointed out, `UseShellExecute` does not do what one thinks on Linux. [#24704](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24704)

I got same results using `UseShellExecute=false` and running `/bin/bash -c "/opt/myservice/update.sh"`.

This script basically runs:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

During package upgrade, *MyService* process is terminated: update script is terminated as well and `apt-get upgrade` is killed as well, leaving inconsistent packages that must be fixed manually.

What I want is that `update.sh` is NOT terminated when *MyService* is terminated.

I tried splitting `update.sh` in 2 parts, the first running the second in different ways

- I tried starting `update2.sh` with `setsid` and `nohup` but I always get same result.
- I tried to execute `update2.sh` script in a new bash shell with `/bin/bash /c "update2.sh"`, same result.

**Question is**: How do I run a script started from a binary and completely detach from binary process, so I can kill binary while script keeps running?

Here's my environment. *MyService* is a binary running as a service. `update.sh` is started by MyService.

**.NET Core** code to start shell script, inside *MyService* binary:

```
var process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // to avoid [defunct] sh processes
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/opt/myservice/update.sh";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(10000);

if (process.HasExited) {
  Console.WriteLine("Exit code: " + process.ExitCode);
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Child process still running after 10 seconds");
}
```

**update.sh:**

```
nohup /opt/myservice/update2.sh > /opt/myservice/update.log &
systemctl stop MyService
```

**update2.sh:**

```
apt-get update >> /opt/myservice/update.log
apt-get -y install --only-upgrade myservice-1.0 >> /opt/myservice/update.log
```

`update2.sh` is never executed because it's terminated when MyService is terminated by `update.sh`.

`update.sh` returns code `143`, it seems it has been killed.

```
2018-08-16 14:46:14.5215|Running update script: /opt/myservice/update.sh
2018-08-16 14:46:14.5883|Update script /opt/myservice/update.sh returned: 143
```

I tried following approaches, thanks for suggestions:

- nohup
- setsid
- disown
- screen
- tmux
- unshare

Every approach has the same result, termination of all spawned processes. 
I suspect this is a **.NET Core** "feature".

Comment: Very unrelated: dont use `UseShellExecute`. It does not do what you think it does on Linux. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24704

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I tried also with `UseShellExecute=false` and running `/bin/bash -c "/opt/myservice/update.sh"` , but result is the very same.

Comment: Have you considered running the script as a separate systemd one-shot service? Or maybe timed if you want regular tests for updated?

Comment: Requested feature is on-demand update. As a dirty solution I did this: a root cron script checks every minute if update scripts exists in `/opt/myservice/updatescript.sh`. If it exists, it is run. When I want to update, .NET Core service executes script.sh: this script copies update2.sh to updatescript.sh, executes it in background and delete it so it's not run again at next cron. It works but it's ugly.